# Página faz submit mesmo com erro na validação

Tags: javascript, jquery, validação

Olá,

Estou tendo problema com uma página porque ela está fazendo submit mesmo quando a validação retorna `false`.

```
    $("#botao1").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url : 'adicionadaIdeia',
            type : 'POST',
            async : false,
            data : $("#form1").serialize(),
            success : document.getElementById("botao2").click(),
        });
        return false;
    });

    function validar() {
            //Verifica se necessidade tem item selecionado
            if($('input[name=Listanecessidade]:checked').length  == 0){
                alert("Selecione uma necessidade!");
                $('input[name=Listanecessidade]').focus();
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Eu queria saber como eu evito que a página faça submit nessa situação (em que o retorno é `false`)

O #botao1 tem a seguinte configuração:

```
<input type="submit" id="botao1" value="Cadastrar">
```

Comment: Que elemento HTML é o `#botao1`? provavelmente precisas de `e.preventDefault();` E com `submit` referes-te ao `ajax` ou o formulário está a recarregar a página?

Comment: o #botao1 é um input

Comment: ... com `type=` a ?? Coloca o html por favor para a pergunta ficar mais clara...

Comment: <input type="submit" id="botao1" value="Cadastrar">

Comment: Ok, testa então com `$("#botao1").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); etc...`

Comment: Victor, clique em [edit] e adicione na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$("#botao1").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();//Para o envio do submit

  if (validar()) {

    $.ajax({
      url : 'adicionadaIdeia',
      type : 'POST',
      async : false,
      data : $("#form1").serialize(),
      success : function() { alert('Requisição enviada com sucesso.'); },
    });

  } else {
    alert("Selecione uma necessidade!");
    $('input[name=Listanecessidade]').focus();
  }

});

function validar() {
  //Verifica se necessidade tem item selecionado
  return !($('input[name=Listanecessidade]:checked').length  == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mude seu `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'adicionadaIdeia',
    type : 'POST',
    async : false,
    data : $("#form1").serialize(),
    success : function(data) {
       document.getElementById("botao2").click(),
    },
    error: function(err){
       //Trate o erro
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que a página não execute submit quando o retorno da função `validar();` for `false` use está condição juntamente com o operador de negação `!`:

```
if(!validar()) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

O `e` é o parâmetro da função que recebe o objeto do evento disparando quando o click no botão acontece, então é necessário declarar este parâmetro em sua função.

Exemplo: `$("#botao1").click(function(e) {...});`.

> Entenda mais sobre o objeto `event` [aqui](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object)
>
> Entenda mais sobre a função `preventDefault();` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault)